# Java mysql connection is error

Tags: java, netbeans-7, mysql-error-1064, mysql-connect

I tried connect mysql in java but there is compiler error.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

I added mysql libraray but this is defective : `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

What should I do?

Comment: You should include the SQL code in your question.

Comment: Your SQL query is probably wrong.

Comment: Are you sure, looks to me as exception not as compile error

Answer (score 1):

`MySQLSyntaxErrorException` means that you are already connected to MySQL but you have some problems with your SQL script, that you're trying to execute.